# hide text between normal text without bad effect on search engine

Tags: html, css

I need put some hidden text between my normal text.

I do it like this:

```
<p>  some text <span class="hide"> hidden text </span>  some text </p>

.hide{display:none}
```

But I worried about bad effect on search engine. how can I hide it without bad effect?

note: I need the hidden text be readble for search engine and print for rss readers...

Answer (score 1):

Partiz, I'm afraid what you want done is just not possible. See:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66353?hl=en

Also, if you must have hidden text, then to somewhat *minimize* bad SEO effects, make a separate page with all the hidden text you want and in the source code of that page, include the following between `<head>` and `</head>`:

```
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX">
```

Also add the following to all anchor tags that link to your rendition of hidden text:

```
rel="nofollow"
```

Depending on how the hidden text is used, make sure users are aware of anything sneaky you do. For example, if your hidden text suddenly appears on a page in the middle of the page after looking at it for five seconds, then at least put a warning about it on the previous page the user looked at.

I'm not sure if anyone will have a better answer than what I can provide here, but the reality is, search engines don't like sneaky acts on websites.